# 4 year consecutive purchase history identification

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to identify customers who has made purchases for 4 years in a row.

The table would have four columns

1. date
2. item
3. id  (a general sequence number)
4. name (can consider this as unique id for customer)

Sample data is as below,

[image]

I have identified consecutive purchases by using a combination of lead and lag functions but after i identified the consecutive purchases how do i identify 4 year consecutive purchases.

sql

```
select
  a.*
)
from
  (
    select
      *,
      case
        WHEN (
          DATE_ADD(
            lag(year, 1, '1900-01-01') over (
              partition by name
              order by
                id asc
            ),
            INTERVAL 12 YEAR_MONTH
          ) = year
          or DATE_ADD(
            lead(year, 1, '1900-01-01') over (
              partition by name
              order by
                id asc
            ),
            INTERVAL -12 YEAR_MONTH
          ) = year
        ) then 1
        else 0
      end as match_col
    from
      inventory
  ) a
  where a.match_col = 1
  
  order by id
```

Sample output

[image]

How i pull out the records 4,5,6,7 (2011 - 2014) for the customer with name "amith" ,skipping other purchases. These are the only purchases which had 4 consecutive year purchases

Expected output would be

[image]

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to aggregate by customer and year and then use `lag()`:

```
select name, yyy
from (select i.name, year(i.date) as yyyy,
             lag(year(i.date, 3)) over (partition by i.name order by year(i.date)) as yyyy_3
      from inventory i
      group by i.name, year(i.date)
     ) ny
where yyyy_3 = yyyy - 3;
```

That is, generate a unique row for each name and year.  Then peak back three rows.  If that row is the current year minus 3, then you have four years in a row.